# Web layout does not auto update after adding a new attribute in GeneXus

Tags: genexus

The symbol on the web layout is different than usual. It is this (when it is not working):
[image]

as opposed to this (when the auto generate is working):

[image]

Is there anyway to fix this. like to re-generate or re-calibrate so that the corresponding attributes are being auto generated in the web layout again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the ovarlay image over the title of the part (in this case the *Web Layout*) shows a round red circle it means that you have manually modified that part, so GeneXus won't update it automatically anymore.

You can reapply the default to that part by going to `Edit -> Apply Default (Web Layout)`.